# Quadratic characters and Liouville's function

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I'm working through the problems in Montgomery & Vaughan's *Multiplicative Number Theory*.  In Section 11.2 'Exceptional Zeros', Exercise 9a says that for a quadratic character $\chi$, show that for all $k\ge 0, x\ge1 $
$$
\sum_{n<x}\frac{\chi(n)}{n}(1-n/x)^k \ge \sum_{n<x}\frac{\lambda(n)}{n}(1-n/x)^k,
$$ 
where $\lambda$ is Liouville's function.  This is elementary.  In part b, under the hypothesis that there exists a $k$ such that
$$
\sum_{n<x}\frac{\lambda(n)}{n}(1-n/x)^k\ge0
$$
for all $x\ge 1$, (no such $k$ is known to exist), one is to show that for all quadratic $\chi$ and all $\sigma>0$
$$
L(\sigma,\chi)>0.
$$
I expect one is meant to use a Mellin transform with Cesàro weighting, S 5.1 in M&V.  The difficulty is that $\chi(n)/n$ are the Dirichlet series coefficients of $L(s+1,\chi)$, not $L(s,\chi)$.  Thus (5.18) gives
$$
L(\sigma+1,\chi)>0
$$ for all $\sigma>0$.

Am I missing something obvious?  Alternately, the method of part a will show that
$$
\sum_{n<x}\chi(n)(1-n/x)^k \ge \sum_{n<x}\lambda(n)(1-n/x)^k
$$
so under the hypothesis that there exists a $k$ such that for all $x\ge1$
$$
\sum_{n<x}\lambda(n)(1-n/x)^k\ge0
$$
one gets $L(\sigma,\chi)>0$ for all quadratic $\chi$.

EDIT: The reason one cares which version of part a is used, is that the numerics for small $k$ and moderate $x$ indicate that positivity is at least plausible for the original part a.  It is not for the revised version.

Of course, one expects that no such $k$ exists in either case.  For $k=0$, the positivity of $\sum_{n<x}\lambda(n)/n$ was known as Turán's conjecture, the *negativity* of $\sum_{n<x}\lambda(n)$ was Pólya's conjecture.  Both where disproved by Haselgrove, and the same methods should generalize for any $k$.

Comment: Maybe you should write to the authors.

Comment: I did, no reply (yet).