Excercise 11.2.9 from Multiplicative Number Theory I. Classical Theory
I have trouble solving the following excercise. This is a result of Bateman & Chowla 1953 The equivalence of two conjectures in the theory
of numbers, J. Indian Math. Soc. (N.S.) 17, 177–181. However I don't have access to this article.
Suppose that $k$ is a positive integer such that
$$\sum_{1 \le n \le x} \frac{\lambda(n)}{n}\Big(1-\frac{n}{x}\Big)^k \geq 0 $$
for all $x \ge 1$, where $\lambda(n)$ is the Louville function.  (a) Show that if $\chi$ is a quadratic character, then
$$ \sum_{1 \le n \le x} \frac{\chi(n)}{n}\Big(1-\frac{n}{x}\Big)^k \geq \sum_{1 \le n \le x} \frac{\lambda(n)}{n}\Big(1-\frac{n}{x}\Big)^k $$ for all $x \ge 1$.
(b) Show that if there is a $k$ such that $\sum_{1 \le n \le x} \frac{\lambda(n)}{n}\Big(1-\frac{n}{x}\Big)^k \geq 0 $ holds for all $x \ge 1$, then $L(\sigma, \chi)>0$ when $\chi$ is a quadratic character, $\sigma>0$.
I have no clue how to prove (a). I've tried to use the fact that $1 \ast \chi \geq 1 \ast \lambda$, from this we get for instance
$$ \sum_{1 \le n \le x} \chi(n) \Big\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \Big\rfloor \ge  \sum_{1 \le n \le x} \lambda(n) \Big\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \Big\rfloor .$$
If we could prove the above without floors, then dividing by $x$ and integrating multpile times in $x$ we would get the desired statement. Please help me.

The exercise is probably incorrect. See https://mathoverflow.net/q/75168/3803 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62883/2689

I thought I'd correct here an error in one of the posts @PeterHumphries linked to in the above comment: the statements sometimes called Pólya's conjecture and Turán's conjecture were never conjectured by those mathematicians—they noted some consequences of those statements that made them less plausible, if anything—and are properly called Pólya's problem and Turán's problem.
